# Java mail api 1.5.5 strange behaviour

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchange-server, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

I am using `javamail (1.5.5)` to fetch mails from exchange `2010 server`. It fails to fetch few messages (`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`). But it is working fine when using `java mail api 1.4.5` without heap space error.

What's strange here is the size of that peculiar message is 136516 Bytes. So when using IMAP, it should be fetched within 9 batches ( default fetch size is 16KB ). But from the debug trace referred below, something is strange.

Here is my code:

```
Message messObj = message[i]; String messSubject = null;
String messMsgId = null;
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
messObj.writeTo(bos);
bos.close();
javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream bis = new javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(session, bis);
bis.close(); mp.setMessage(cmsg);
messSubject = cmsg.getSubject();
messMsgId = ((MimeMessage) cmsg).getMessageID();
System.out.println("debugging:::subject::"+messSubject+"::msgid::"+messMsgId);
```

---

> FLAGS (\Seen \Answered))|
>   [14:48:21:205]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: A3893 OK FETCH
>   completed.| [14:48:21:205]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: A3894
>   FETCH 1 (BODY[]<536512690.16384>)|
>   [14:48:21:220]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: * 1 FETCH (UID 91149
>   BODY[] {137921}|
>
> FLAGS (\Seen \Answered))|
>   [14:48:21:236]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: A3894 OK FETCH
>   completed.| [14:48:21:236]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: A3895
>   FETCH 1 (BODY[]<536650611.16384>)|
>   [14:48:21:251]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: * 1 FETCH (UID 91149
>   BODY[] {137921}|
>
> --5c3ef07b8737170331214bb435ce7be6--| [14:48:21:267]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]:  FLAGS (\Seen
>   \Answered))| [14:48:21:267]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: A3895
>   OK FETCH completed.| [14:48:21:267]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]:
>   A3896 FETCH 1 (BODY[]<536788532.16384>)|
>   [14:48:21:283]|[09-26-2018]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[73]: * 1 FETCH (UID 91149
>   BODY[] {137921}|
>
> ---

Error occurs before the system print. Each time the entire message is fetched and it is fetched for 3896 times ( after that memory heap error occurs and stops the process ). Could someone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Please share your code here too.

Comment: I have added the code.